# Using Json data as function parameter

Tags: javascript, json

I've been recently trying a develop a simple application, which would use user input, convert it to json and use that json in another function to draw graph. I managed to output correct json to console, but when I try to call it as a parameter in the function which uses it to draw graph, it fails to work. If I manually copy console output directly to the plotting function it works normally. So the question here is, how does one use Json as a function parameter.

graph obj:

```
var graph = {
        "nodes": [],
        "edges": []
    }
```

..some code which fills graph (irrelevant here).. ending with a function call:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(graph, null, '\t')); //works perfectly if manually copied
        var inpt = JSON.stringify(graph, null, '\t');
        execute(inpt); //doesn't work
```

And the execute() with the json line:

```
execute(input)
elements: input,
...some more code...
```

Comment: Why is it that you just not pass the graph object to the execute function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass the JSON string. Instead pass the `graph` object directly. The [JSON](http://json.org/) (JavaScript Object Notation) format is native for JavaScript. The JSON string representation is used to transfer the object to environments that does not support it directly, for example consuming a JSON object in a service written in C# or Java.

When an object in JavaScript `var o = { field: "value" };` is passed as an argument to a function `function f(p) {...}`, then in the function the field can be accessed directly `p.field...`.

When the object is needed outside the JavaScript scope, then it should be serialized to a JSON string `{ "field": "value" }`. The recepient can retrieve the field and the value from the string following the JSON construction convention. [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is used for object serialization.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was obviously a very noobish mistake, this works perfectly.

Comment: Glad that the answer helped.